# Haskell trouble with returning in functions

Tags: haskell, if-statement, return

```
while :: Int -> Bool -> (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) ->[Int] -> String
while arguments validity premRange atomRange operators = 
     return(if validity then "Hello" else "NO")



main :: IO()
main =
    do   
putStrLn "Welcome to Random Argument Generator"
arguments <- getArguments
validity <- getValidity
putStrLn "Enter the range of the number of premises to each argument"
premRange <- getRange
putStrLn "Enter the range of the number of atomic statments per premises"
atomRange <- getRange
operators <- getOperators
putStrLn "Thank You!\nExecuting..."
test <- while arguments validity premRange atomRange operators
putStrLn "Good Bye"
```

Its complaining about my return in while and my call to it. i made this function as a test and im really confused as to what its complaining about exactly.

Comment: `return` in Haskell does not mean what it means in other languages. For normal functions, you will never need to use `return`.

Comment: what about IO functions i used return in those and they worked but is that for some other reason

Comment: @user2150839, `return` in Haskell is specifically about `IO` (and other monads); namely it makes an `IO` computation out of a pure value.  `return :: a -> IO a`

Comment: @user2150839: In a normal language returning a monad from a function would look like `return IO("xxx")`. In Haskell, the return statement is implicit, the monad constructor is called `return` and the `"xxx"`stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell an expression such as an `if` expression is a perfectly fine definition for a function. You can just remove the word `return`.

After that, you're going to have a problem in `main` where one line doesn't do I/O, so its type isn't compatible with the surrounding `do` (I think):

```
test <- while arguments validity premRange atomRange operators
```

But, aha, you can change it to:

```
let test = while arguments validity premRange atomRange operators
```

Comment: hmm yes trying to figure out why aswell

Comment: Turns out that i need to make it an IO string which i dont exactly understand why and then keep the if statement as a return. i thought IO mainly was for outputting to a file or screen not assigning to something in a IO function

Comment: ooooooooo thats right <- only applies to IO only i remember now its all coming back now! thank you!

Comment: if you use 
`let test = while ...`
you won't need to make the string an IO